# What does it mean: "a move operation is never implicitly defined as a deleted function" in C++Primer 5th edition?

Tags: c++

I am reading "C++ Primer", 5th edition. And I can not understand the following passage. It comes from page 538~539.

> Unlike the copy operations, a move operation is never implicitly defined as a deleted function.

Never? But aren't all the definitions mentioned later implicit?

> However, if we explicitly ask the compiler to generate a move operation by using `= default` (§ 7.1.4, p. 264), and the compiler is unable to move all the members, then the move operation will be defined as deleted. With one important exception, the rules for when a synthesized move operation is defined as deleted are analogous to those for the copy operations (§ 13.1.6, p. 508):
>
> - Unlike the copy constructor, the move constructor is defined as deleted if the class has a member that defines its own copy constructor but does not also define a move constructor, or if the class has a member that doesn’t define its own copy operations and for which the compiler is unable to synthesize a move constructor. Similarly for move-assignment.
> - The move constructor or move-assignment operator is defined as deleted if the class has a member whose own move constructor or move-assignment operator is deleted or inaccessible.
> - Like the copy constructor, the move constructor is defined as deleted if the destructor is deleted or inaccessible.
> - Like the copy-assignment operator, the move-assignment operator is defined as deleted if the class has a const or reference member.

Comment: It sounds like the passage might be saying that while it won't define a move operation as deleted for you, if you explicitly request one as `default` under those circumstances it will be defined as deleted. But that first quote just appears to be [incorrect](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor), even if it's possible to reconcile it with the second quote.

Comment: I think the first quote may be to express something like Class has non-static data members that cannot be moved.@NathanPierson